# UITableViewCell sizing with optional image (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, interface-builder

I am having a doozy of a time trying to figure this one out:

I have a `UITableViewCell` with a fixed sized `UIImage` (250 x 250) pinned to the top of the cell's `View` and a `UILabel` of variable text size underneath with its top pinned to the bottom of the `UIImage` and its bottom to the bottom of the cell's `View`.

I have a use case where an image is **not always guaranteed** and so the image view *purposely* collapses to `0` height so it does not break autolayout on the `UILabel`'s top pinning.

I assumed that this would allow the `UITableViewCell` to shrink down to the size of the label but instead, it stays the default height and autolayout stretches the label's height (to maintain the pinning to the top and the bottom) with the text centered in the middle.

I used all the usual suspects, `UITAbleViewAutomaticDimension` and `estimatedRowHeight` blah blah (what you would probably suggest first!) and it was to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

I did see something about changing the **Priority** for the constraints in IB to `250` instead of `1000` so they could break. And also some references to resizing the `UITableViewCell` manually (lame and nasty) by calling `requiredHeight()` on the `UILabel` which broke the layout, so what am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Please answer my additional questions: Your imageView (if filled) has always size of 250? Your imageview has height of 0 if image no available? Your label height has also fixed size? Did you try to rather set spacing between imageview and uilabel, than to set uilabel to be 0px spaced from top like you did? What you have in your func heightForRowAt(:)?

Comment: Did you set any content-hugging priority on the label's height?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have a use case where an image is **not always guaranteed**

For this situation you can create 2 type of `UITableViewCell`: the first one with `UIImageView` and the second without it. Then, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` init the cell you want.

Comment: You sir are a true hero. I have been developing for a long long time without knowledge of **multiple** Prototype Cells. I am now a grateful fool. Thank you!